# Why (Not?) Pass Context to Android ViewModelFactory

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel, viewmodelfactory

I am refactoring applications that pass "application context" to the view model factory and is accessed in the view model. Is there a definitive opinion if this coding practice is good/ bad/ or OK? For example, I use it to call data repository that loads a data file from the assets directory. If there is a "better practice", where is it documented?

Code snippets

```
class MainViewModelFactory(private val applicationContext: Context) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
    if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(MainViewModel::class.java)) {
        return MainViewModel(applicationContext) as T
```

....

```
class MainViewModel(
    applicationContext: Context
    ) : ViewModel() {....

    init {
        _dataIsLoaded.value = dataRepository.myFunction(applicationContext, Constants.data_file_name)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s perfectly fine as long as the context you store in a ViewModel property truly is the Application Context and not some Activity instance, for some example. You could ensure this by calling `applcationContext` on it and passing that to the ViewModel constructor in the factory.

If the application Context is your only ViewModel constructor parameter, you should subclass AndroidViewModel and then you don’t even need a factory because the default implicit factory can already handle it.